# DrawingVisual, DrawingContext and Visual Class for Silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight

Can anyone tell me how or where to get any class or dll for **DrawingVisual**, **DrawingContext** and **Visual** Class for **Silverlight**?

I am trying to import a WPF program to Silverlight for creating custom polygons on runtime by setting points with mouseclick.

The WPF program uses these three classes, but they are not available in Silverlight.

Please suggest.

Comment: Unfortunatelly Silverlight does not support drawing by code via the Render method of DrawingContext.

Comment: isn't there any alternate way to achieve that functionality?

Answer (score 1):

As already said by sa_ddam213, there is no such thing in Silverlight available out of the box. However you could implement that yourself. After all all of the calls in DrawingContext translate to corresponding Visuals (FrameworkElements in SL) so instead of calling e.g. DrawRectangle (or whatever) you would instead add a Rect Shape to the Visual Tree into a Container (e.g. Canvas). However unless you have a lot of code in WPF that you need to convert "automatically", I suggest you take the direct approach and change the calls to instead directly create the elements and add them to the Visual Tree. We have used to latter approach when we converted our WPF library to Silverlight and have been very pleased with the results - the performance does not suffer too much at all from this.